# What is the name of complex functions with poles and branch cuts?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know the most "well-behaved" complex functions on a domain are called holomorphic.  If the only singularities in the domain are poles, we say the function is meromorphic on the whole domain, or we say it's holomorphic everywhere EXCEPT at the poles.  It seems to me that the same logic applies to functions with branch cuts: they can be holomorphic everywhere EXCEPT along some curve, i.e. the singularities we're trying to exclude occur on a line instead of at countably many points.  So what do you call such a function on a domain that includes the branch cut contour?

Comment: Well, we call those holomorphic on some subdomain :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is called a [*global analytic function*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_analytic_function), or a *complete analytic function* if it contains all possible analytic continuations.